# unable to connect laptop to cisco vpn when laptop is using tablet internet connection

Tags: wi-fi

I am facing an unusal problem. I tried searching but seems no earlier post is here addressing my problem.

I am using 3G mobile data connection(SIM card) in my samsung galaxy tab 2. As you know android Jelly Bean has the feature of sharing the tablet's data connection via wifi tethering/hotspot. Now: I can connect to the internet easily from my acer laptop(windows 7) via the wifi tethering of my tablet. However, when i try to connect my laptop to my office vpn(cisco) using cisco vpn client, i get the error that the client is not able to connect to the vpn server. But if i connect my laptop to the internet via bluetooth modem of my nokia c7, then vpn connection is easily established.

Is it something with the wifi tethering technology? Please help. The tablet itself can connect to vpn server using vpncilla for android.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that whereas the bluetooth connection functions as a bridge network device, Wifi tethering creates a NAT which may prevent some functionality. See if enabling Transparent Tunneling or IPSEC over UDP on the client help. Since tethering doesn't support port forwarding, you can't use PAT on the device.